# c: char* , malloc, возврат из функции, и снова возврат в Java(jni)

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, jni, malloc

Хочу попытаться понять ситуацию:
Посмотрите код и комментарии:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* getstring(){
    size_t unknown_string_length = 1000; //допустим 1000, но количество на самом деле неизвестно
    char* returned = malloc(unknown_string_length);
    sprintf(returned, "%s", "очень много букв");
    return returned;
}


jstring Java_com_mycompany_myndkapp_HelloJni_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz )
{
    char *result = getstring();

    //Когда под переменную выделена память с помощью malloc, то переменную надо освобождать, ОК
    free(result);    
    //но что тогда возвратится в джаву, как поступить в данном случае ? 
    //какие есть способы вообще ?

    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, result);
}
```

Вот как поступить в даном случае , чтобы было правильно ?

Comment: jstring Java_com_mycompany_myndkapp_HelloJni_stringFromJNI(    JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz )
        {
            char *result = getstring();        
            char output[strlen(result)];
            strcpy(output, result);
            free(result);        
            return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, output);
     }


Я попробовал сделать, нормальный это способо, или это вообще лишнее ? Может что лучшее посоветуете ? (что то не правится этот коммент в нормальный вид )) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавать уже освобожденную память в функцию, очевидно неверно.

Никогда не писал с JNI, но попробуем разобраться (угадать).

Читаем [документацию](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#NewStringUTF) и видим, что `NewStringUTF` возвращает сформированный  Java string object.

Будем надеяться, что переданные байты *копируются* куда-то внутрь JVM. Тогда код может выглядеть так:

```
 jstring Java_com_mycompany_myndkapp_HelloJni_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz )
 {
   char *result = getstring();
   jstring res = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, result);

   // Когда под переменную выделена память с помощью malloc, то переменную надо освобождать
   // ОК -- надеемся, что содержимое result[] скопировано
   free(result);    
   // а res (Java string object)  возвратится в джаву
   return res;
 }
```

Попробуйте, вдруг и в самом деле я угадал.

Comment: Спасибо, завтра уже загружу Монстро Андроид Студио, а то сегодня уже голова болит. А что насчет моего верхнего коммента , если ваш не пройдет (хотя сомневаюсь), мой подойдет  ? Ваш вопрос засчитаю пожалуй, спасибо что помогаете ...

Comment: По поводу комментария, то в нем просто еще один лишний буфер и сдается мне что в самом вопросе вообще можно обойтись и простым static char[MAX_LINE_LENGTH] массивом, однако без контекста трудно точно сказать.

Comment: То есть создать еще один параметр в функции getstring чтобы передать туда static char[MAX_LINE_LENGTH] ?